# How to replace URLs not within a href tag in JSP

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = ' www.stackoverflow.com  <a href="http://www.somesite.com">somesite</a> www.othersite.org ',
rex = /(<a href=")?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)+\w+/g;    
str = str.replace( rex, function ( $0, $1 ) {
    return $1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + $0 + '">' + $0 + '</a>';
});
```

I want to implement this logic in JAVA / JSP can any one help me plz

Comment: so you want to make othersite.org to look like somesite.com?

Comment: Or were you looking to replace all sites listed in 'str' with some other site?

Comment: i want to replace all weburl from clients to be in a href tag, to be clickable